# Photoshop CS6 on Wine Performance Improvement

Tags: graphics, wine, performance, winetricks, photoshop

So I'm running Photoshop CS6 on Wine on Ubuntu 14xx. My issue is once I get deeper into work (fairly large images), the performance drops...a lot. When I ran Photoshop on Windows using the same PC, I could get a lot more performance out of it.

I have a couple of ideas...

- Increase RAM flow to Photoshop. Specifically designate a lot more RAM and performance to go to Photoshop.
- Adjust some settings on Wine?
- Add a Windows Partition (Will it slow down Ubuntu?)
- New graphics card?

Any help is appreciated?

Comment: i have no issues with PS6 on ubuntu 14.4, maybe you are using ubuntu not as primary OS or your PC is old a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Having more memory (RAM) always helps because you typically need 3x as much ram as the largest image when it is uncompressed.  Add in the requirements for WINE and Ubuntu and that is a lot of ram.

Check if it is swapping to disk a lot, if so, you have little choice but to buy more ram or somehow allocate more to the process.  It is possible to reduce the ram used by Photoshop (at least in older versions) - check out he caching settings.

Sorry I don't have anything more specific.